# Are shared variables supported in Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Spark provide two limited types of shared variables for two common usage patterns: broadcast variables and accumulators, are they supported in Spark Streaming??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use them as you'd normally do via `SparkContext`. The only difference is that you need to get it from `SparkStreamingContext`:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyApp")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(1))
ssc.sparkContext.broadcast(myValue)
```

With spark streaming you might want to update that value at some point, to do that you should use [unpersist()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/broadcast/Broadcast.html#unpersist()) (or the blocking version) and broadcast again.